# How to remove "All Products" item in main menu of Commerce Kickstart 2?

Tags: routes, commerce

I checked vocabulary collection, no "All Products" there.

Is it created programmatically? How can I remove/change this item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove it at admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu (deselect the tickbox)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I couldn't find it, But I got it in admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu eventually. This question is a pseudo-question.